# Alert Dialog- Getting Error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show the alert dialog inside a class which extends with arrayAdapter.

I am getting this error

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Here my code, what i have tried

```
public class DeteteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Gold> {
private int contexts = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
private Context context;
private List<Gold> subjects = new ArrayList<Gold>();
private TextView subject;
private TextView date_day;
private TextView time;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String name;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://ayyappagold.com/ayyappa/test.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

public static String month;
public static String year;

public DeteteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Gold> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.subjects = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.subjects.size();
}

@Override
public Gold getItem(int index) {
    return this.subjects.get(index);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        // ROW INFLATION
        Log.d("ExamAdapter", "Starting XML Row Inflation ... ");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gold, parent, false);
        Log.d("ExamAdapter", "Successfully completed XML Row Inflation!");
    }

    // Get item
    Gold text = getItem(position);
    subject = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    String content = text.content;

    String times = text.time;

    subject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            name = getItem(position).id.toString();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("This item will be deleted")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    new DeleteProduct().execute();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });





    subject.setText(content.replace("*", "\n"));

    return row;
}
```

Plz help me to show the alert dialog in this class

Comment: Can you post the rest of your logcat?

Comment: 04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at com.ayyapa.gold.DeteteAdapter$1.onClick(DeteteAdapter.java:131)

Comment: 04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-09 11:56:59.216: E/AndroidRuntime(2764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

Comment: Try to use v.getContext() while creating the dialog

Comment: Can you plz tell me v means what

Comment: hey still am getting the same error

Comment: Could you show code, where DeleteAdapter constructor is used?

Comment: public DeteteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Gold> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.subjects = objects;
}

Comment: Plz anyone tell the alternate solution for this problem

Comment: Can you make edits to the original question rather than posting these things as comments?

Comment: Looking at your code, chances are that the context you're trying to use is null. Could you show us where you instantiate the `DeteteAdapter` class, and which context you're passing to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. And i am really happy to share with you,

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        v.getRootView().getContext());
```

Use **v.getRootView().getContext()** instead context or v.getContext()

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( DeteteAdapter.this);
```

Comment: i am getting this error "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(DeteteAdapter) is undefined"

Comment: getApplicationContext() is not visible in the list and getContext() also not working..

Comment: yes. I am sure, the problem is in alert dialog, because with out alert its working perfectly

Comment: Try `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());`

Comment: What you mean by  name = getItem(position).id.toString() in OnClick()?

Comment: Gettin id value from the class Gold

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
```

change this line like ;

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                (Activity)context);
```

maybe it can help you